# npm ERR! While resolving: react-number-format@5.1.2

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, expo

I want to use react native number formatter in my app so i tried installing it by running `npm install react-number-format` according to their doc but i get the error below

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: dummyapp@1.0.0
npm ERR! Found: react@18.0.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"18.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react@"^0.14 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0 || ^17.0.0 || ^18.0.0 || 
^18.0.0" from react-number-format@5.1.2
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-number-format
npm ERR!     react-number-format@"*" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^18.2.0" from react-dom@18.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react-dom
npm ERR!   peer react-dom@"^0.14 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0 || ^17.0.0 || ^18.0.0 
|| ^18.0.0" from react-number-format@5.1.2
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-number-format
npm ERR!     react-number-format@"*" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency 
resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /Users/ricky/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/ricky/.npm/_logs/2023-01-03T18_24_08_563Z-debug-0.log
```

so i used `--force` and was able to install and use it. But when i build my app on the eas server same error occurs while installing dependency.

this is complete log from eas server

```
Running "npm install" in the root dir of your repository 
2
[stderr] npm ERR!
3
[stderr] code ERESOLVE
4
[stderr] npm
5
[stderr] ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
6
[stderr] npm ERR!
7
[stderr] npm ERR! While resolving: react-number-format@5.1.2
8
[stderr] npm ERR! Found: react@18.0.0
9
[stderr] npm
10
[stderr] ERR! node_modules/react
11
[stderr] npm ERR!   react@"18.0.0" from the root project
12
[stderr] npm ERR!   peer react@">=16.3.0" from @callstack/react-theme- 
provider@3.0.8
13
[stderr] npm ERR!   node_modules/@callstack/react-theme-provider
14
[stderr] npm ERR!     @callstack/react-theme-provider@"^3.0.7" from react- 
native-paper@4.12.5
15
[stderr] npm ERR!     node_modules/react-native-paper
16
[stderr] npm ERR!       react-native-paper@"^4.12.5" from the root project
17
[stderr] npm ERR!
18
[stderr] 1 more (@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs)
19
[stderr] npm ERR!   26 more (@react-native-community/masked-view, ...)
20
[stderr] npm ERR! 
21
[stderr] npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
22
[stderr] npm ERR! peer react-dom@"^0.14 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0 || ^17.0.0 || 
^18.0.0 || ^18.0.0" from react-number-format@5.1.2
23
[stderr] npm ERR! node_modules/react-number-format
24
[stderr] npm ERR!   react-number-format@"^5.1.2" from the root project
25
[stderr] npm ERR! 
26
[stderr] npm
27
[stderr] ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@18.2.0
28
[stderr] npm ERR! node_modules/react
29
[stderr] npm ERR!   peer react@"^18.2.0" from react-dom@18.2.0
30
[stderr] npm ERR!   node_modules/react-dom
31
[stderr] npm ERR!     peer react-dom@"^0.14 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0 || ^17.0.0 
|| ^18.0.0 || ^18.0.0" from react-number-format@5.1.2
32
[stderr] npm ERR!     node_modules/react-number-format
33
[stderr] npm ERR!       react-number-format@"^5.1.2" from the root project
34
[stderr] npm ERR! 
35
[stderr] npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
36
[stderr] npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
37
[stderr] npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency 
resolution.
38
[stderr] npm
39
[stderr] ERR! 
40
[stderr] npm ERR! See /home/expo/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.
41
[stderr] 
42
[stderr] npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
43
[stderr] npm ERR!     /home/expo/.npm/_logs/2023-01-03T18_13_57_944Z-debug- 
0.log
44
npm exited with non-zero code: 1
```

even when i run `npm install` without `--force` i still get same error but if i remove react number format everything works fine.

please what is the right version of  react number format i will install to fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

this is a reactjs package will not work in react-native

Comment: still did not work

Comment: try npm install react-number-format --force

Comment: my bad, this is a reactjs package will not work in react-native, updating my original post

Comment: none for react native?

Comment: What are you trying to solve that you need a package